# Validate non-existing field in WTForms and Jinja

Tags: flask, jinja2, wtforms, validationerror

after long searching and no answers I have to ask you for help.

Im developing app in Flask, using WTForms.

Im trying to validate form, but Im not validating specific field. In every tutorial or documentation I found how to catch validation error in Jinja

{% if form.field.errors %} and so on...

How can i catch validation error if I have no specific field? How to catch general error in Jinja?

Here is my Form and template:

```
forms.py
class VacationForm(FlaskForm):
    vac_start = DateField('Start Vacation', validators=[DataRequired()])
    vac_end = DateField('End Vacation', validators=[DataRequired()])
    half_day = BooleanField('Half Day')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    def validate(self):
        start = self.vac_start.data
        end = self.vac_end.data
        if start > end:
            raise ValidationError('error')

template.html

<form method="POST" action="">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
     {{ form.vac_start(class='form-control col-6',type='date') }}
     {{ form.vac_end(class='form-control col-6',type='date') }}
        {{ form.half_day }}
     {{ form.submit }}
  </form>
```

I always get to error page, but i want output error somewhere under submit button or datefield.
I believe that Im doing something easy but I just cant figure it out.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just append the error to the field:

```
self.submit.errors.append("My message")
return False
```

Don't raise a ValidationError - simple return False in the case of validation error (and return True otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

So I got idea, to validate vac_end field and it somehow works :D

Here is code.

```
    vac_start = DateField('Start Vacation', validators=[DataRequired()])
    vac_end = DateField('End Vacation', validators=[DataRequired()])
    half_day = BooleanField('Half Day')
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')

    def validate_vac_end(self, vac_end):
        if self.vac_start.data > vac_end.data:
            raise ValidationError('Wrong dates')


{% if form.vac_end.errors %}
        {% for error in form.vac_end.errors %}
            {{ error }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
```